# Maven Invoker Plugin not detecting failed test

Tags: maven, maven-3, integration-testing, pom.xml, maven-invoker-plugin

As part of a root parent pom project, several integration tests have been added to test it on sample projects.

The structure of the project folder is as following:

```
-root-maven-parent-project
    |- src
    |   |-it
    |      |-sample-project-test1
    |      |-sample-project-test2
    |      |-sample-project-test3
    |      |-settings.xml
    |- pom.xml
```

**The main issue is**: although the build of `sample-project-test2` is wrongly failing (it should not), the build is `SUCCESSFUL` for the Invoker plugin and the overall build does not fail.

Here is the concerned `maven-invoker-plugin` configuration:

```
<profile>
    <id>it-tests</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Integration tests configuration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <streamLogs>true</streamLogs>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                        <goal>generate-sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
                    <failIfNoProjects>true</failIfNoProjects>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test-release</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/its/sample-project-test1</cloneProjectsTo>
                            <pom>src/it/sample-project-test1/pom.xml</pom>
                            <properties>
                                <scmBranch>release-something</scmBranch>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test-hotfix</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/its/sample-project-test2</cloneProjectsTo>
                            <pom>src/it/sample-project-test2/pom.xml</pom>
                            <properties>
                                <scmBranch>hotfix-something</scmBranch>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test-master</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/its/sample-project-test3</cloneProjectsTo>
                            <pom>src/it/sample-project-test3/pom.xml</pom>
                            <properties>
                                <scmBranch>master</scmBranch>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

As you can see, multiple executions are configured because each execution would need its own properties. Each execution is also pointing at its own integration test project and pom.

The build is clearly failing for a specific execution:

```
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 2.337 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-04T17:35:49+02:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 12M/220M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-snapshot-management) on project cmp-sample-project-test2: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[INFO]           pom.xml .......................................... FAILED (4.1 s)
[INFO]   The build exited with code 1. See C:\data\git-repositories\root-maven-parent\target\its\sample-project-test2\build.log for details.
```

However, at the bottom of the build we see that the `verify` goal of the `maven-invoker-plugin` aggregated the results, flagged the concerned test as `Passed` and made the build `SUCCESS`:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-invoker-plugin:3.0.0:verify (integration-test-release) @ root-maven-parent ---
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Build Summary:
[INFO]   Passed: 1, Failed: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-invoker-plugin:3.0.0:verify (integration-test-hotfix) @ root-maven-parent ---
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Build Summary:
[INFO]   Passed: 1, Failed: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-invoker-plugin:3.0.0:verify (integration-test-master) @ root-maven-parent ---
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Build Summary:
[INFO]   Passed: 1, Failed: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Moreover, by only running the failing test from command line as:

```
mvn invoker:integration-test@integration-test-hotfix invoker:verify -Pit-tests
```

The sub-build of the test project fails, the output is correctly marked as `Failed` in the test summary, and the build is correctly ending with `FAILURE`.

**Question**: why when executing multiple integration tests using the `maven-invoker-plugin`, although a test is failed, it is marked as `Passed` in the test summary and the build does not fail, while running only the isolated test everything fails correctly?

Note: no [invoker property file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html#invokerPropertiesFile) is used.

Comment: Which files do you see in the reportsDirectory, i.e `${project.build.directory}/invoker-reports`. If it's only from the third execution, then there's your answer.

Comment: @RobertScholte in that folder I got the `invoker-summary.txt` file, empty, and the `BUILD-pom.xml.xml` file, 2 lines, stating build successful and its duration. Strangely, the current execution properly aggregates the results of all the test at its end, however results are always positive regardless of the real sub-build result. This is a strange behavior (aggregating, but wrongly) anyway, imho

Comment: @RobertScholte please see my answer below. Issue solved, although I still think something could be improved in the plugin. Shall I report in its official JIRA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue solved** with the following explanation, although I think something could be improved in the behavior of the plugin (see below).

The whole `maven-invoker-plugin` was reduced to the following configuration:

```
<profile>
    <id>it-tests</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Integration tests configuration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <streamLogs>true</streamLogs>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                        <goal>generate-sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
                    <failIfNoProjects>true</failIfNoProjects>
                    <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/its</cloneProjectsTo>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test-release</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Basically: only one plugin execution, instead of an execution per test, which indeed was verbose and non scalable, but forced by the need of having different values for the same property in each integration test. Apparently, this is not possible via pom configuration and only achievable - unless I am not mistaken - via a [`test.properties`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#testPropertiesFile) file.
Hence, as a complement to the configuration above, I added in each and every integration test project folder a `test.properties` file with the following content e.g.:

```
scmBranch=master
```

De facto replacing what in the `pom.xml` file was (as part of an execution of the `maven-invoker-plugin`:

```
<properties>
    <scmBranch>master</scmBranch>
</properties>
```

This mechanism (single execution of the plugin + test properties file per test folder) fixed the issue, allowing the build to have multiple integration tests each with its own different value for the same property. Hopefully this solution may help troubleshooting similar issues.

Here is the final result from the build correctly aggregating tests and effectively respecting their sub-build output (while before the build was generating 6 `Build Summary` of `Passed: 1` each time, although not correct).

```
[INFO] --- maven-invoker-plugin:3.0.0:verify (pom-integration-test) @ root-maven-parent ---
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Build Summary:
[INFO]   Passed: 6, Failed: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

However, **some questions remain**:

- Without using the `test.properties` file, how to achieve the same via `pom.xml` configuration? Normally, it should only be an alternative, not a mandatory and only possible solution. That's why this is rather a uncomplete feature (a bug?) to me.
- Having multiple execution of the plugin results in test summaries at the end of the build which correctly follow the executions order, the number of tests executed (always 1 per execution, in this case), but apparently do not reflect the effective result of each sub-build. Why? This is rather a bug or a misbehavior of the plugin due to an unexpected usage of it, perhaps.

Comment: Regarding the first bullet: if the value for `scmBranch` is unique per test, then you you need to configure it per test. You could also set this value within the `<properties>` of the pom of the specific it. It's not a bug, but I'm wondering what you had in mind.

Comment: @RobertScholte indeed, setting it in the pom file of the it-test project would also make the trick, but I wanted to simulate an external injection, since the properly normally comes from the parent pom or from our CI server. Just for purity. Then I agree, first bullet is not a bug, although we allow more configurability via file than via pom. Second bullet is still unclear to me as a behavior.

Comment: It must have to do with the files in the report-directory. The code isn't that complex, see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugins/invoker/VerifyMojo.html#L103

Answer (score -1):

use this configuration :-

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <rules>
                <banDuplicateClasses>
                    <findAllDuplicates>true</findAllDuplicates>
                </banDuplicateClasses>
            </rules>
            <fail>false</fail>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>extra-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

for more refer this link :

http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/

Comment: Not sure why you thought the enforcer plugin would help on this issue and especially why the banDuplicateClasses rule would have anything to do with it. Hence: no, this is definitely not helpful. The broken build snippet posted in the question is indeed mentioning the enforcer plugin, but just because it is used to properly break the build, which is a desired scenario, as described in the question itself.